# Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("chat", null) in the _CustomTabViewState

Tags: flutter, flutter-routes

I have a set of routes that I have defined in the `routes.dart` and these routes are linked in the `main.dart` file as below.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<ConnectivityStatus>(
          create: (_) => ConnectionService().connectionStatusController.stream,
        ),
        ...
        ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthNotifier>(
          create: (_) => AuthNotifier(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        routes: Routes.routes,
        home: SplashScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

#### `Routes.dart` file:

```
class Routes {
  Routes._();

  static const chat = '/chat';

  static final routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    chat: (BuildContext ctx) => CircleChat(),
  };
}
```

I have a button that is triggering the above route but throwing error.

```
FlatButton(
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(Routes.chat);
)
```

#### Error -

> The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
> Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("chat", null) in the
> _CustomTabViewState. Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:
>
> 1. For the "/" route, the "builder" property, if non-null, is used.
> 2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
> 3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by "builder" and "routes".
> 4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called. Unfortunately, onUnknownRoute was not set.
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      _CustomTabViewState._onUnknownRoute.

**P.S. - For a similar error I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59488673/flutter-could-not-find-a-generator-for-route-routesettings-homepage-null) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52405521/could-not-find-a-generator-for-route-home-page-in-the-materialappstate/52406650#52406650), but I didn't find the explanation, that why it is not working when all semantics are correct.**

Comment: I cannot see the `billPayments` route inside your Routes file

Comment: Aah.. sorry typo... it's `chat`

Answer (score 0):

Use **routes** or **onGenerateRoutes** property in **CuptinoTabView of CuptinoTabBar** and pass your routes or onGenerateRoutes arguments here.